# Additional information: 'xsl:template' cannot be a child of the 'TABLE' element

Tags: html, xml, templates, xslt

I have this error in my xsl file: 'xsl:template' cannot be a child of the 'TABLE' element.

Is it likely to be my xsl file, or the c#?

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="Table1">
  <HTML>
    <BODY>
      <TABLE BORDER="2">
        <TR>
          <TD>Item_Code</TD>
          <TD>Item_Description</TD>
          <TD>Current_Count</TD>
          <TD>On_Order</TD>
        </TR>
        <xsl:template select="book"/>
      </TABLE>
    </BODY>
  </HTML>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Table1">
  <TR>
    <TD><xsl:value-of select="Item_Code"/></TD>
    <TD><xsl:value-of select="Item_Description"/></TD>
    <TD><xsl:value-of select="Current_Count"/></TD>
    <TD><xsl:value-of select="On_Order"/></TD>
  </TR>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

For `<xsl:template select="book"/>` try substituting `<xsl:apply-templates select="book"/>`.

If you have just slapped your forehead and cried D'oh!, then go in peace and sin no more.

Otherwise, you'll find that a good XSLT tutorial will help you a lot.

Comment: Cheers, and so quick!

Comment: Now I am getting a c# compiling error!

// Test code //
            // Load the style sheet.
            XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
            xslt.Load("style1.xsl");

Comment: You will probably want to ask follow-on questions as separate questions on Stack Overflow.